# How to add the ListView element to be referenced in the individual Activity files

Tags: java, android, xml

The app crashes as soon as any of the list Activities are launched:

```
NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter' on a null object reference
```

My instructor says its happening because the layouts haven't been configured correctly. Right now, the **list_item** is being inflated as the Activity layout. Please create a separate layout, such as **activity_list** and add the ***ListView element there to be referenced in the individual Activity files***

Here's the code

MainActivity

```
package com.example.tourguide;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button event = (Button) findViewById(R.id.events);
        Button mall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.malls);
        Button resturant = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resturants);
        Button university = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uinversities);

        event.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent event = new Intent(MainActivity.this, events.class);
                startActivity(event); }
        });

        mall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent mall = new Intent(MainActivity.this, malls.class);
                startActivity(mall);
            }
        });

        resturant.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent resturant = new Intent(MainActivity.this, resturants.class);
                startActivity(resturant);
            }
        });

        university.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent university = new Intent(MainActivity.this, universities.class);
                startActivity(university);
            }
        });

    }}
```

WordAdapter.java

```
package com.example.tourguide;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.LayoutRes;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class WordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<listitem> {
    public WordAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<listitem> listitems) {
        super(context, 0, listitems);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if(listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }

        listitem currentItem = getItem(position);

        TextView name = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        name.setText(currentItem.getName());

        ImageView image = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.image1);
        image.setImageResource(currentItem.getImage());

        TextView dist = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        dist.setText(currentItem.getDist());

        TextView price = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        price.setText(currentItem.getPrice());

        return listItemView;
    }

}
```

listitem.java

```
package com.example.tourguide;

import android.widget.ImageView;

public class listitem {

    private  String name="";
    private int image;
    private  String dist="";
    private  String price="";

    public listitem(String namea, int imagea, String dista, String pricea){
        name = namea;
        imagea = image;
        dist= dista;
        price=pricea;
    }

    /*********** Set Methods ******************/

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setImage(int image)
    {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public void setDist(String dist)
    {
        this.dist = dist;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price)
    {
        this.price = price;
    }

    /*********** Get Methods ****************/

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public int getImage()
    {
        return this.image;
    }

    public String getDist()
    {
        return this.dist;
    }

    public String getPrice()
    {
        return this.price;
    }
}
```

Univerisities.java

```
package com.example.tourguide;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class universities extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_item);

        ArrayList<listitem> listitemArrayList = new ArrayList<listitem>();
        listitemArrayList.add(new listitem("Prince Sultan University", R.drawable.u1, "AlNarjes Dist", "$"));
        listitemArrayList.add(new listitem("Princess Nourah University", R.drawable.u2, "AlNarjes Dist", "$"));
        listitemArrayList.add(new listitem("King Saud University", R.drawable.u3, "AlNarjes Dist", "$"));

        WordAdapter adapter = new WordAdapter(this, listitemArrayList);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.tourguide.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="29sp"
        android:textColor="#3DC195"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="Tour Guide App" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#6AA13F"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="Tour Guide App is designed to help you discover Riyadh city sightseeings including events, malls, resturants and universities.the app will be developed periodically to add more features... stay tuned" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/events"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Events"
        android:onClick="onClickEvent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/malls"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Malls"
        android:onClick="onClickMall"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/resturants"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Resturants"
        android:onClick="onClickRest"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/uinversities"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Universities"
        android:onClick="onClickUniv"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image1"
                    android:layout_width="163dp"
                    android:layout_height="96dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="68dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#DB0BA4"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                   />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text2"
                        android:layout_width="113dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#456233"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                   />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text3"
                        android:layout_width="113dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#C1B03D"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                   />

            </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the file `Univerisities.java` you should change your layout file to `activity_list.xml`.

Line

```
setContentView(R.layout.list_item);
```

Must be changed to :

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
```

Comment: the app still crashes

Answer (score 0):

Bro,

First you are trying to inflate the ListView item into you activity, which is wrong:
Change the `setContentView(R.layout.list_item)` to `setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);`

Also please check out the ViewHolder pattern for ListView's since the your adapter's getView method should be improved by that to make scrolling even more smooth:

```
  View listItemView = convertView;
    if(listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }
```

and if no items are appearing in the list, you should also override the getItemCount on adatpterto return the size of the list.